# Is my soft body mesh flawed for soft body physics?

Tags: physics, collision, soft-body

I want the "Pachi Shell" to behave like a semi-rigid plushi. I've spent several hours tweaking stiffness, push/pull, self collision, etc, but I can't get the results I want before it the mesh acts sporadically. The mesh is all quads.[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please be more precise about what you want, why you're not glad with the result, and also share the file with the Soft Body that you've set?

Comment: The file is in there. There should be a baked animation already applied that is stable, but doesn't have the plushy-like physics I want. Edit: sorry, I uploaded the wrong one.

Comment: You've shared a file but I can't see any Soft Body for the objects, and if you've baked the animation it is in your computer. Please share the object with the Soft Body and tell a bit more about why you're not glad

Comment: I uploaded the right file now

Comment: What about enabling Stiffness and Self Collision?

Comment: Both make the physics unstable, especially the stiffness.